# Request value from eval query string passed in anchor tag

Tags: asp.net, string, anchor

I passed three values as query string in an anchor tags as follows.

```
<a href='Booking.aspx?date=<%# Eval(" + calendar.Text + ")%>&hour=<%# Eval(" + i + ")%>&Id=<%# Eval(" + c.Id + ")%>'>Booking</a></td>";
```

When i go to Booking.aspx the link look likes this.

```
http://localhost:50115/AltaDeReserva.aspx?date=%3C%# Eval(08/07/2014)%>&hour=<%# Eval(17)%>&Id=<%# Eval(8)%>
```

But i don´t know how to request the values, i tried this but it does not work.

```
String date= Request.QueryString["date"].ToString();
```

Thank you in advance..

Comment: where is the `<a href=' ...` exists in the page (part of gridview columns or a form control)? where does `calendar`, `i` and `c.id` come from?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<a href='<%# string.Format("Booking.aspx?date={0}", Eval("date")) %>' />
//OR
<a href='<%# "Booking.aspx?date=" + Eval("date") %>' />
```

If above code is not worked for you then elaborate your scenario.

Comment: I need to insert in html with innerHtml so i think i am having problems with the ""

Comment: Please replace " with \" or with single quotation. If possible then please provide your sample data. So, We will try to solve your issue.